# Creating dot notation functional component with TypeScript/ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to work out how to create a dot notation component and everything I've found on SO and Google doesn't appear to work in the way that I am expecting.

I have the following code for two components; at the moment, it's all in one file:

```
const ThreeDotMenu : any = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <ul className='absolute bg-primary-light text-white'>
                {children}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}

const Item : React.FC<DefaultProps> = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <li>{children}</li>
    )
}

ThreeDotMenu.Item = Item;
export default ThreeDotMenu;
```

And I am using it as follows:

```
<ThreeDotMenu>                                                                            
   <ThreeDotMenu.Item>item</ThreeDotMenu.Item>                                                                         
   <ThreeDotMenu.Item>item 2</ThreeDotMenu.Item>
</ThreeDotMenu>
```

This is working fine except the parent component isn't type. Instead I am using `any` as the type.

I am now trying to type it by changing the declaration to be:

```
const ThreeDotMenu : React.FC<DefaultProps> = ({children}) => {}
```

The component itself is happy, however the declaration where I do `ThreeDotMenu.Item = Item` now throws an error with the following:

> Property 'Item' does not exist on type FC

And my `DefaultProps` is typed as follows:

```
export interface DefaultProps {
    children: Array<React.ReactNode>|React.ReactNode
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by having a `.Menu` component that acts as the parent component.

```
import React from 'react';

const Menu: React.FC<DefaultProps> = ({children}: any) => {
    return (
        <>
            <ul className='absolute bg-primary-light text-white'>
                {children}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}

const Item: React.FC<DefaultProps> = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <li>{children}</li>
    )
}


const ThreeDotMenu = {Menu, Item}
export default ThreeDotMenu

<ThreeDotMenu.Menu>                                                                            
        <ThreeDotMenu.Item>item</ThreeDotMenu.Item>                                                                         
        <ThreeDotMenu.Item>item 2</ThreeDotMenu.Item></ThreeDotMenu.Menu>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCrQgDsBneAWSToFcAuRYmAOgBiAYQA8AESSYU7ADYwACjjAMAfHAC8cABQBvNAAtgMgCZE6AX24o6ATwCUGtTqpxXcIjHZQ62l2-8iKn7+IXAisnBoMigMDAByKCBI6vgoAEYMEDLsMEhwaQDmALRgUKAoUDZFMsAF+vC5AB4wRQDuhrn4QZShvW56hiZm5sF9YQD0st19IuPTbnZUI9SUtIzwAJK5INzI6PzC4pLScooQymqaugZGpmzmDupOox5ePlqjATUqA7fDs99RotKMsaPQmHAACr6IhIMQQGCsDgaOA6JHsAA0cC2SBAyyQjUgsDgxmOsng0Nh8MRbHYVDB6zgjRRWkezx6ble3l8HNcIkpSDhCPRfHRajGEslUulMtCnzc-JhgupIpxIBUwG2swFQppHD4avFsuNJtNIXlfJ1KtpBu2Gu2cAATNqlbrVXbRi6qcKbWKgUsgA)

If you want to use the parent without the dot, you can just let the compiler figure the types out instead of giving explicit types.

```
const ThreeDotMenu = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul className="absolute bg-primary-light text-white">{children}</ul>
    </>
  );
};

const Item = ({ children }) => {
  return <li>{children}</li>;
};

ThreeDotMenu.Item = Item;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThreeDotMenu>
      <ThreeDotMenu.Item>item</ThreeDotMenu.Item>
      <ThreeDotMenu.Item>item 2</ThreeDotMenu.Item>
    </ThreeDotMenu>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work. Is that expected through as I thought the parent didn't require the dot notation, it was only the child of the parent that had the dot notation.

Comment: It's possible, you just have to remove the types and let the compiler infer the type. You can give explicit types, but this is just easier. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to [*not use*](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) `React.FC`, as suggested in @nullptr's answer.

If you really want to use it, you can add an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with your extra properties that you assign later on:

```
const ThreeDotMenu: React.FC<DefaultProps> & {
    Item: typeof Item
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAESXoFcAbGABRzAGc4Ab1JwxcNAAtgHACZFKALjgBBKFBQBPADzJ0MAHR6MAOQiykAPjgAfRMUPGYZi6QC+5NBEr94AFUkiJCYIGABZJEo2ZScDADEAYW0Wdi5eCAFrADJhUXEASRoQZRhNMCQITDhCpBB3OABeOAAKIQlpOQU4NwBKRusRcTgiGDYoSha8obFtSynpoe1OCQ4Ufn4TFBAkBoByFAAjfggONho4A4BzAFowKFAUKE1rjmBLyXgaAA8Ya4B3aQ0XZzBag8RCKQyeSRDxgxYAek4INB2nhyLEPXcnm8vmqRRiDniSRSKE4PD4-GsTVa7ShXV6-VyQxGYwmzXmi1elghHWhlDcqK580xHlIASCIXCkTYBhqeCacoA3ORmn0GtZ2YtxUhgqEIlF0dNtNrdVKorKipZgEVUSbJfqZXLDVrAjr7dKLbUrUU4AAmW2u00Oz0gQ0BiV66VzTFAA)